# Okta Java SDK Email Factor Verification Not Returning Success

Tags: java, okta

I am following the Okta Java Sdk documentation where I am trying to enroll an email factor then activate it then verify it and I am stuck at verifying the factor, where even though I set the right passCode(one time verification code) that I received in my email, the factorResult in the response is always CHALLANGE and it never comes as SUCCESS.

This is the code I am following from the docs
https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java#verify-a-factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it where I had to use the parameterized verify method where I had to pass the verifyFactorRequest as first parameter and I set the other parameters to null like this:

```
VerifyUserFactorResponse verifyUserFactorResponse = factor.verify(verifyFactorRequest,null,null,null,null,null);
```